# Passing a list from a table in a view in asp.net mvc 4 to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model with a parameter that's a list of another model. I want to show that list as a table, have a check box to select some elements, and then I want to press a button and send the list of elements to another view.

I'm having problem receiving the list of AlbumViewModel, or the StoreViewModel in the controller, it's always null, I tried many things, but I always end up with an empty parameter.

I simplified the code to start from there, but I still can receive a model in the controller. This is the code I have (without the check box part, since anyway I receive an empty model)

```
@model StoreViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowSelected", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "uk-form 
uk-margin-top" }))
{
<table id="albumTable" class="uk-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Albums.First().ArtistId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Albums.First().ArtistName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Albums.First().GenreId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Albums.First().Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Albums.First().Price)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Albums)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ArtistId)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArtistId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(i => item.ArtistName)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.ArtistName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(i => item.GenreId)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.GenreId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowSelected(List<AlbumViewModel> model)
{
   return View("ShowSelected", model);
}
```

Models

```
public class StoreViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<AlbumViewModel> Albums { get; set; }
}

public class AlbumViewModel
{
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong? And how to solve this task?

Thanks

Comment: I vaguely remember needing to use the index of the entry when submitting collections, so the name includes its index eg. `name="Albums[0].ArtistId"`.  Using the default helpers produces `name="ArtistId"` iirc.  Can you confirm what the names are for those hidden fields?